# "node-gyp rebuild" error in mac

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

I wanted to follow [this page](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/blob/master/docs/running-your-own-jsbin.md) to run JSBin locally.

I just installed `xcode 8.2` in my mac. Now, `npm -v` returns `3.10.9`; `node -v` returns `v7.2.1`. However, `npm install` raised errors:

```
/Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin$ npm install

> hashring@3.0.0 install /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/node_modules/hashring
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/hashvalue/src/hashvalue.o
In file included from ../src/hashvalue.cc:1:
../../nan/nan.h:189:68: error: too many arguments to function call, expected at most 2, have 4
    return v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), receiver, argc, argv);
...
...
...
...
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
13 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/hashvalue/src/hashvalue.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.2.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/node_modules/hashring
gyp ERR! node -v v7.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN mocha-casperjs@0.5.8 requires a peer of casperjs@>= 1.1.0-beta3 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.2.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! hashring@3.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hashring@3.0.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hashring package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs hashring
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls hashring
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/npm-debug.log
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`hashring` v3.0.0 depends on an older version of `nan` (v1.3.x)](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-hashring/blob/d30bf43503fc60eec307b57652a37fc4f26770e9/package.json#L28), which is not compatible with recent versions of node. It should be noted that as of this writing, the current version of `hashring` (v3.2.0) no longer contains an addon, it's javascript only.

The `hashring` dependency comes from `jsbin`'s `memcached` dependency, which is currently hard coded to a specific git commit hash. There was [a PR to update this dependency](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/pull/2794) a number of months ago but was apparently dismissed because the maintainer(s) are apparently not interested in supporting modern versions of node. You may want to create an issue on [their tracker](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/issues) to voice your concern about node compatibility.

Comment: So what should I do? How could I let it use `hashring v3.2.0` rather than `v3.0.0`?

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade Node to v10, like this:

```
brew uninstall node

brew install node@10

brew link --force --overwrite node@10
```

`npm i` should finish without errors now.

Comment: Downgrading node from node 16 (current head) to node@14 for me on Catalina 10.15.7 following these steps